# Case sensitive logon on some users

Tags: oracle, password

Looking for a way to let selected users have case-sensitive logon check on Oracle 12.1. Setting SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = TRUE enables *all* users to have case sensitive logon, but trying to limit that to some.

Defining a profile having a verify function which checks for at least one upper and lower letter seems to only check when changing the password, but not upon logon.